# Changing Browser Title in Tab

Tags: civicontribute

We've created a contributions tab in CiviCRM and made the page live. However, when you're on that live page and filling the form out, the title of the website up in the browser tab says "CiviCRM -- [Our Domain]"

Is there any way to change or mask that language so users aren't confused that may have left our site?

Comment: Can you give some additional details, eg what CMS and theme you're using? The CiviCRM [demo sites](http://demo.civicrm.org) don't exhibit this behaviour. [CiviCRM / Drupal demo](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1) = contrib page title | site title; [CiviCRM / Joomla demo](http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php/component/civicrm/?task=civicrm/contribute/transact&id=1&action=preview&reset=1) = contrib page title; [CiviCRM / WordPress demo](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/contribution-page/) = contrib page title | site title.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris comments, it's weird that it's showing this. But you could always use a *template*.extra.tpl file to set the page title by Javascript.

1. Create a directory, if you haven't already, for template customisations. Then tell CiviCRM about it at Administer » System Settings » Directories which is at `/civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1`
2. Find the template name of the form that's being used from the comments in the page source of the page(s) you need to change. e.g. for *all* contribution pages its `CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl`.
3. Create the same directory structure in your custom templates directory and then place a file called `Main.extra.tpl` (using the example form name from (2)) and in that file place something like

   ```
   <script>document.title="You're still on my website :-)";</script>
   ```

.extra.tpl files are processed after the main template file is, so this script will run and set the window's title.

It's a hack, and in this case sounds like it shouldn't be necessary, but it's something you can use.